# Is elasticsearch phrase aggregation exist?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, phrase

I know that with ES you can find the top most terms in a document. But how about phrase count? I checked the internet and couldn't find any answer. Is there a way to find top most phrases in a document with ES?
for example; top terms aggregation returns result like; 
          "

```
            { key": "and",
              "doc_count": 11
            },
            {
              "key": "is",
              "doc_count": 9
            },
            {
              "key": "do",
              "doc_count": 9
            },
            {
              "key": "new",
              "doc_count": 9
            }
```

what I want is something like top phrases returns result ;

```
 {
      "key": "New York",
      "doc_count": 11
    },
    {
      "key": "is here",
      "doc_count": 9
    },
    {
      "key": "do job",
      "doc_count": 9
    }
```

Is it possible? Yes it is :)

I was able to get phrase count. Now I need to filter my aggregations result. My result is ;

```
{
      "key": "New",
      "doc_count": 11
    },
    {
      "key": "New York",
      "doc_count": 9
    },
    {
      "key": "do ",
      "doc_count": 9
    },
    {
      "key": "do job",
      "doc_count": 9
    }
```

The thing I want to do is getting the aggregations result that has 2 or more terms in it. Is it possible? In this case "New" and "do" should not appear in the aggregations result, only "New York" and "do job" should appear.

Comment: How do you define "phrase"? A phrase can mean many things. Do you mean a sentence starting with a capital letter and ending with a period or something else? Of any length or only the N first words?

Comment: updated the question. @Val

Comment: Ok, so you define a phrase as two consecutive tokens, is that right?

Comment: yes, that is the case.It can be 3 also. Is it possible? Mr. @Val

Comment: I've found this:https://www.elastic.co/blog/searching-with-shingles but I've a stemmer plugin that I developed. Can I combine these two analyzer in my mapping for indexing?

Comment: updated the question mr. @Val